# How to extract text from specific bounding boxes in an image using pytesseract?

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, text-extraction, bounding-box

[Image with bounding boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxjZP.jpg)

[Image without bounding boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFok8.jpg)

My goal is to extract all the data written under "SHIP TO" heading.

Here's the code that I have written so far where I am trying to extract specific text from an image(purchase order), where the bounding boxes are generated for the image. I have used pytesseract.

In the attached image I want to extract everything written under the "SHIP TO" heading.

Is it possible to create just a single bounding box around everything written under the "SHIP TO" header as it is currently creating bounding boxes around each word of text or is it possible to specify which bounding boxes I want to extract the text from and how do I extract the text from the bounding boxes?

```
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
import cv2
img_path=r"C:\Users\mihir\settls\PO\POs\images\img-1.jpeg"
img=cv2.imread(img_path)
d=pytesseract.image_to_data(img,output_type=Output.DICT)
n_boxes= len(d\['level'\])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    x,y,w,h=d\['left'\]\[i\],d\['top'\]\[i\],d\['width'\]\[i\],d\['height'\]\[i\]
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)][1]
```

Comment: Please provide the image that without red rectangular box or whether this is the original image?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried the same raw image with easyocr.

```
import easyocr
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'], gpu=False)
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
result = reader.readtext('1.jpg')
print(result)
Total = []
for (bbox, text, prob) in result:
    Total.append(text)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = bbox
    tl = (int(tl[0]), int(tl[1]))
    tr = (int(tr[0]), int(tr[1]))
    br = (int(br[0]), int(br[1]))
    bl = (int(bl[0]), int(bl[1]))
    cv2.rectangle(image, tl, br, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv2.putText(image, text, (tl[0], tl[1] - 2),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4, (255, 0, 0),1)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (16,16)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
print(' '.join(Total).split("SHIP TO", 1)[1])
```

the output result is,

```
[([[19, 83], [249, 83], [249, 103], [19, 103]], 'PO ISSUED ON: 24-Jan-2022', 0.9183683480821002), ([[363, 83], [429, 83], [429, 103], [363, 103]], 'BILL TO', 0.8261962973493113), ([[358, 108], [486, 108], [486, 132], [358, 132]], 'Dtwelve Spaces', 0.9999498894624934), ([[515, 109], [545, 109], [545, 129], [515, 129]], 'Ltd.', 0.8132303953170776), ([[19, 121], [215, 121], [215, 141], [19, 141]], 'PO #: TRN_01-2022_890', 0.7749007835581628), ([[357, 135], [597, 135], [597, 155], [357, 155]], 'Znd Floor, 14th main, 17th cross', 0.5247519586101493), ([[19, 156], [243, 156], [243, 177], [19, 177]], 'DEPARTMENT: Procurement', 0.999899568358847), ([[359, 161], [571, 161], [571, 182], [359, 182]], 'Sector-7 HSR Layout; Hosur', 0.9069650417811701), ([[19, 195], [259, 195], [259, 215], [19, 215]], 'PO START DATE: 24-Jan-2022', 0.990964755896037), ([[355, 183], [532, 183], [532, 209], [355, 209]], 'Sarjapur Road Layout;', 0.8457916918023463), ([[358, 210], [550, 210], [550, 234], [358, 234]], 'BANGALORE, Bengaluru', 0.877072846004521), ([[19, 231], [243, 231], [243, 251], [19, 251]], 'PO END DATE: 28-Feb-2022', 0.9841029716507399), ([[356, 236], [590, 236], [590, 260], [356, 260]], '(Bangalore) Urban; Karnataka', 0.7698963854349542), ([[18, 267], [240, 267], [240, 293], [18, 293]], 'SCOPE OF WORK: Supply &', 0.6945534614684448), ([[359, 263], [411, 263], [411, 283], [359, 283]], 'GSTIN', 0.9999916833215784), ([[419, 263], [573, 263], [573, 283], [419, 283]], '29AAGCDO4IZPIZD', 0.6757562812584058), ([[19, 295], [107, 295], [107, 315], [19, 315]], 'installation', 0.8406179275099799), ([[357, 299], [429, 299], [429, 319], [357, 319]], 'SHIP TO', 0.841328703547502), ([[356, 322], [580, 322], [580, 348], [356, 348]], 'Birchgrove 101,Durga Saffron', 0.849745329973732), ([[356, 349], [608, 349], [608, 375], [356, 375]], 'Square,Kariyammana Agrahara,', 0.7643241366913213), ([[358, 375], [616, 375], [616, 401], [358, 401]], 'Bellandur; Bengaluru; Karnataka-', 0.7938083186961036), ([[358, 400], [626, 400], [626, 426], [358, 426]], '560103,Bangalore Karnataka,India', 0.7202288946116454), ([[485.02871413764274, 108.25168544775693], [514.8382900600361, 112.21216140284166], [511.97128586235726, 129.74831455224307], [483.1617099399639, 125.78783859715834]], 'Pvt:', 0.5378595619172015)]
```

The output image be like

[image]

Hope this will help you. You can install easyocr by `pip install easyocr`.
If you print text variable, You can gain the combine bbox out of **SHIP TO** and also the data of SHIP TO is

```
Birchgrove 101,Durga Saffron Square,Kariyammana Agrahara, Bellandur; Bengaluru; Karnataka- 560103,Bangalore Karnataka,India Pvt:
```

Comment: Please make sure this will work for your case. Thank you

Comment: How exactly do I obtain this data-"Birchgrove 101,Durga Saffron Square,Kariyammana Agrahara, Bellandur; Bengaluru; Karnataka- 560103,Bangalore Karnataka,India Pvt:"

On  doing print(text) , it doesn't give the same result.

I'm sorry it may seem like a very stupid question , I'm not really familiar with easyocr , would be great if you could link some references to use easyocr to extract text from pdf/images. Appreciate the help , thanks alot.

Comment: Sorry i can't get it. Can you explain once?

Comment: Yep, I edited the previous comment

Comment: In last line of the code i had extracted the **SHIP TO** as per you requirement. For reference of Easyocr you can go through the official repo https://github.com/jaidedai/easyocr

Comment: while you do print(text), It return the line by line detection. Thats what i attached the last line of the code.